# Relative path for imread in python

Tags: python, opencv

I cant set the relative path for the DSC_1902.JPG image(in the "Res" directory) in `imread`. Following is my project structure:

> BasicAI Server/Res/DSC_1902.JPG
>
> BasicAI Server/Computer_Vision/FD.py

The following code is in `FD.py`

```
import cv2
def detect():

    img = cv2.imread('\BasicAI Server\Res\DSC_1902.JPG')
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

detect()
```

Comment: Typo: single backslash should be double backslash inside string literals. You want `'\\BasicAI Server\\Res\\DSC_1902.JPG'`. HOWEVER, Python should be able to understand forward slashes....

Comment: @RayToal This doesnt work also img = cv2.imread("\\BasicAI Server\\Res\\DSC_1902.JPG")

Comment: @MujtabaFaizi You should probably loose the "\\" in the beginning

Comment: @FlyingTeller Still no progress

Comment: Yes you did say "Relative path" in your question but you used an absolute path in your code. Hard to figure out what it means but I think @FlyingTeller is right

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: @RayToal  Any path from within the project would do but not from the root like C:/... The error: cv2.error: C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\color.cpp:11111: error: (-215) scn == 3 || scn == 4 in function cv::cvtColor

Comment: Hmm that's strange, the error is showing up in C++ code. Sorry I'm stumped.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is better to avoid slashes in the paths by using the `os.path.join` function to build the platform independent path string.

Relative path can be converted to absolute path using the functions `path.join` and `getcwd` from the `os` module as follows:

```
import cv2
import os
def detect():
    absolute_path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'BasicAI Server', 'Res', 'DSC_1902.JPG');
    img = cv2.imread(absolute_path)
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

detect()
```

This will work provided the code is executed from the parent directory of **BasicAI Server** directory.

Comment: But this cant be used if I want to access the image from a sub package like from "Computer_Vision" ?

Comment: @MujtabaFaizi.. Then instead of `os.getcwd`, you will have to provide the relative address of parent directory using `..` like this: `os.path.join('..', 'BasicAI Server', 'Res', 'DSC_1902.JPG');`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pathlib` to navigate through directories

```py
import cv2
from pathlib import Path

def detect():
    path = Path('.').absolute().parent / Res / DSC_1902.JPG
    img = cv2.imread(str(path))
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

detect()
```

Where `Path('.')` means current directory (I assume You are in `Computer_Vision` folder).